# How to use Support Vector Mashines and ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to do some simple classification or pattern recognition with some Machine Learnings Tools like OpenCV and ROS. Im new in this field and dont know much about it. Any examples or help to be find in web or ROS world?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72964/how-to-use-support-vector-mashines-and-ros?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to learn SVM, try [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/).

You can write C++ code and call roscpp API.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use OpenCV, have a look at the cv_bridge.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-08-15**:
Thanks. As I can see from wiki cv_bridge is used to convert ROS images into OpenCV images and vice versa. Im not interesting in only data images. I wont to use datas from laser scans and Imu , so not only images.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-15**:
In that case OpenCV won't work.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-08-15**:
ok. thanks